# How to kill a process of mysql workbench in windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I was importing a sql file in mysql workbench and in the process I clicked "Open" instead of "Run SQL Script", now that I want to import it correctly I get this error

> [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used
> by another process:

How can I get the process to drop it or stop it?

Comment: There is a white hand in a red octagon just above where you type your query. This stops processes.